# Exception while accessing maxmind's GeoIP-country.mmdb database through hive

Tags: hive, geoip, maxmind

I have a custom hive UDF to access Maxmind's **GeoIP-country.mmdb** database that is added to the hive resources through "add file pqr.mmdb". The compiled UDF is added as "add jar abc.jar" 
When I run a hive query, behind the scenes the java class tries to access the data in geo database and fails by throwing the following exception.

```
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.maxmind.db.Reader$FileMode
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at com.maxmind.geoip2.DatabaseReader$Builder.<init>(DatabaseReader.java:68)
```

I tried the following two lines separately but it still throws the same error. My database file and jar's are all added to hive resources.

```
reader = new DatabaseReader.Builder(database).fileMode(Reader.FileMode.MEMORY_MAPPED).build();
```

AND

```
reader = new DatabaseReader.Builder(database).fileMode(Reader.FileMode.MEMORY).build();
```

Has anyone experienced a similar issue ?
Thanks !
- Lalith

Comment: You mention that all the JARs are added, but from the exception, it appears that you are missing [com.maxmind.db](https://github.com/maxmind/MaxMind-DB-Reader-java). What JARs have you added? See [this ZIP file](https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-java/releases/download/v0.8.0/geoip2-0.8.0-with-dependencies.zip) for all the required JARs.

Comment: Beautiful ! I used the geoip2 maven dependency and configured the pom to add all my required dependencies into the compiled jar. But looks like that didn't happen in this case, causing this issue. Adding the jars you provided solved it. Would you mind if I asked you where you downloaded these jars from ? Looks like not all of them are geoip2 related. Or are they dependent on each other ? Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

(Moved this to an actual answer.)

The [geoip2-0.8.0-with-dependencies.zip file](https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-java/releases/download/v0.8.0/geoip2-0.8.0-with-dependencies.zip) contains all of the JARs that the API depends on. The ZIP file is created during the build of GeoIP2. The included JARs are all dependencies or dependencies of dependencies listed in the [pom.xml file](https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-java/blob/master/pom.xml). The zip is listed on the [releases page](https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-java/releases).