# How to add dependencies for maxmind geoip2 eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, dependencies, geoip

I'm trying to use [MaxMind's GeoIP2 database](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/), I've added the jar to my Java build path and configured it with Javadoc and source but when I run the program I get a NoClassDefFound error, which according to this stack overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373364/exception-while-accessing-maxminds-geoip-country-mmdb-database-through-hive) is because I need to add the dependencies, but I have no clue how to add them in eclipse, I tried extracting the jar files and adding them to the build path but that didn't work, how do I do this in eclipse?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You add the dependencies the same like you did it with the other ones. Or use  [maven](https://maven.apache.org/)

Comment: Like I did with what other? I don't want to use maven, I prefer eclipse

Comment: eclipse is your IDE and maven is a dependeny management tool. It should  used together because its makes life easier.

Comment: Oh, isn't there just a simple way to do it in eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In eclipse you have to create a new `maven java project`. If you dont know `maven` you can get informations here:

[apache maven startsite](https://maven.apache.org/)

[how to install maven](https://maven.apache.org/install.html)

Afer that you are able to configure your dependencies in your `pom.xml` file. Which is the configuration file for maven.

You can find some dependencies for your usage here:

[maxmind documentation](http://maxmind.github.io/GeoIP2-java/)

The include of the dependency would look like this:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.maxmind.geoip2</groupId>
    <artifactId>geoip2</artifactId>
    <version>v2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But first, you should look at maven installation and using. It will make your life easier by handling all the necessary dependencies you will need in this project and in all of your other projects in future.

Answer (score 0):

**You don't need to use Maven**

For Eclipse, you may use `Rightclick on Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Add External JARs`. Select the JAR file you downloaded.